# Question about testIamPermissions method in Billing API

Tags: api, google-cloud-platform, billing

I'm trying to use `cloudbilling.billingAccounts.testIamPermissions` in the APIs Explorer, but I get an error.

API URL
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=ko#p/cloudbilling/v1/cloudbilling.billingAccounts.testIamPermissions?resource=billingAccounts%252F01183E-6A3E97-BE2C7A&resource=%257B%250A%257D&_h=1&

Error Result
{
 "error": {
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
  "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
 }
}

The error message appears as 'Request contains an invalid argument', so the value entered in resource seems to be incorrect.

I entered `billingAccounts / {billingAccountID}` for resource, but I do not know why I get an error.

`{billingAccountID}` has entered the billing account ID you are using.

What value should be put in the resource?

Comment: You need to include your API request. Also, do not include screenshots. Copy by hand the text of the screenshot. Links break, pictures are deleted, etc. If that happens in the future your question will not be useful to help others.

Comment: Don't include pictures, type the text in. The reason is that pictures don't work for text searches. Also include the API request.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use your full ID "billingAccounts/012345-567890-ABCDEF`" as an string. Also avoid to share your private information for security reasons use examples instead.

Confirm that the [other options of the API](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/billing/cloudbilling/v1/) works for you.